# Is it possible to see the source code of the current installed version of Rust?

Tags: rust, archlinux

I am using 64bit Arch Linux and have installed `rustc 1.0.0-dev (built 2015-02-23)`; this is the latest version in Arch (which is a rolling release).

I am getting a compilation error when trying to compile gcc 0.3.2.
I added `gcc` as a dependency in `Cargo.toml` and the compilation failed:

```
.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/gcc-0.3.2/src/lib.rs:225:35: 225:58 error: unresolved name `io::ErrorKind::NotFound`
.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/gcc-0.3.2/src/lib.rs:225         Err(ref e) if e.kind() == io::ErrorKind::NotFound =>
```

I tried to verify the source, but I can't find where the source code is located. I looked in `/lib/rustlib/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu`, but that only contains compiled code.

**edited:**

I tried to figure out the api of the current install rust lib, Shepmaster give the answer that there is doc attached to the lib.
in arch it's located at /usr/local/share/doc/rust/html/std/index.html

Comment: Could you please include more details? For example, which version of `rustc` do you have? Judging by the error, you're probably using an old version. (The ecosystem tracks the *nightly* version of Rust, at least until there's a stable 1.0. So try using `rust-nightly-bin` in the AUR.)

Comment: That is a very old `rustc` at this point. You need to upgrade, otherwise you won't make it very far. Rust is an open source project: https://github.com/rust-lang/rust

Comment: The `gcc` crate source code is here: https://github.com/alexcrichton/gcc-rs

Comment: I'll second @BurntSushi5's suggestion to upgrade. You may be interested in an [Arch nightly build of Rust](https://github.com/michaelsproul/rust-nightly-archlinux), and installing Rust yourself isn't hard at all, and there are [tools to help](https://github.com/brson/multirust) with that. Seeing the source of your installed version would be up to the Arch package. You could look at that package to see where it pulls from, and then track the source there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the source for any packages in Arch Linux repository, you should use the Arch Build System.

1. Install the `abs` using `pacman`
2. Run `abs` as `root` to synchronize the package tree
3. Copy the corresponding directory from `/var/abs/<repo>/<pkgname>` (in the case of `rust`, that would be `/var/abs/community/rust`) to where you want to build the package.
4. Navigate to that directory and run `makepkg -o`. This command will download and unpack the source automatically into the current directory.

Reference: [Archwiki article on ABS](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Arch_Build_System)

Comment: thanks, so there is no way to know it from the compiled lib somehow,
i dont understand how one should know which API is installed currently on his system, and i guess there isn't any

Comment: @Tomer Rust itself does not bundle the source code — it is a compiled language and the installer only installs the binary bits and some documentation. Interpreted languages like Ruby ship with source code because that's what is actually used at runtime. You could look at the local documentation to see what public types and methods are available, if your version of Rust is new enough that it includes it and the package you are using chooses to install it.

Comment: local doc is what i was looking for, thanks Shepmaster!!